# Cannot open android-studio

Tags: android, intellij, openjdk

I installed `android-studio` few days back along with `openjdk`. And it did work fine until yesterday. But now I cannot open it. The desktop icon is dead and when I run `./studio.sh` it shows

```
JDK Required: Cannot load a JDK class: com.sun.jdi.Field.
Please ensure you run the IDE on JDK rather than JRE.
```

But `openjdk` is still there. I am runnning on fedora32. android-studio is in `opt/` and openjdk in `var/lib/`

Comment: Output of `which java`, `java -version`?

Comment: `which java`--> `/usr/bin/java`  `java -version` --> `openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: Open Cmd program and type `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `echo %JDK_HOME%`. What are outputs?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably changed the program file location, or renamed the folder it was in. The desktop icon should be a shortcut to the `studio.exe` in the Android Studio program files. That's why the desktop icon is dead as it links to a non-existent file address.
Check where the program files for Android Studio were installed `which java`. Try renaming the containing folder if possible and/or you like. Otherwise just set/create environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to `Android Studio\jre`. It should work fine

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank your for your contribution. The syntax and file/path names you use imply that the solution was intended for a Windows machine - please review the answer carefully to ensure it also works on the Fedora Linux environment used by to OP.